Does the increasing number of co-authors per paper justify not having publications in top conferences?
I'm currently drafting a research proposal but I don't have publications in top-tier journals or conferences. Observing recent trends, it seems that the average number of co-authors per paper in prestigious conferences has increased significantly. Many papers now result from large collaborations, which might make it more challenging for individuals who received their Phds at countries with relatively low ranking universities (ranked as such by lets say sites that globally rank universities).
So I was thinking about using this as a justification since most of my papers have either one or two authors but I am not sure if it has a high chance of backfiring.
The argument would have been that the author teams tend to be from elite institutions, primarily US universities who are more culturally compatible or have other things in common. Such research clusters might make it exponentially more difficult than it was lets say 20 years ago for outsiders to have their papers accepted at top avenues . But the answers here convinced me that I shouldn't make such argument.

Does the increasing number of co-authors per paper somewhat justify not having
publications in top conferences?


What is your goal for making this argument? Just about everything has a reason, but naming it doesn’t change that things  are as they are.

@MisterMiyagi To justify my lack of paper contributions to top journals and conferences in a way that doesn't outright indicate limited research ability in my part.

Don't compare too much, do your own research well and own it. At which career stage are you, btw?

No, it doesn't justify anything and I doubt that the phenomenon you see has much effect on papers getting accepted or rejected at reputable conferences. The paper reviewers focus on the paper and what it contributes to the literature, not on the authors or, especially, on the number of authors.
That said, in some subfields of some fields it is difficult to carry on research unless you have large collaborations. Think CERN which has output a few papers where the list of authors is longer than the paper itself.
Likewise, coming from a country with low ranking universities (your words) isn't an excuse either, but it does make things more difficult unless you can develop collaborative relationships, probably abroad. It is difficult to come up with meaningful ideas when working in a vacuum. This is why many universities with large departments also have a number of focused working groups for faculty and graduate students.
It is why international conferences are important. I used to go to a lot of conferences around the world. Luckily I got financial support for this. But I found the conferences just as useful if (and when) I wasn't presenting anything. Meeting and talking to people got some ideas flowing and the collaborations developed into future publications.
Once you meet someone who shares your interests it is now much easier than in the past to keep in contact and keep the ideas flowing. Things like Zoom, for example, let you work in real time, face to face (screen to screen?). I started out in the era when "mail" meant typed or written on paper, in envelopes, with stamps. I'm not so old as the Pony Express era, though.
For most of us, being isolated makes things difficult. I was in such a situation early in my career and developed only later when I learned the above lessons and began to act on them.
Even being at a small teaching college in the US can make it difficult to publish if you can't find people to collaborate and share ideas with.

The argument would have been that the author teams tend to be from elite institutions, primarily US universities who are more culturally compatible or have other things in common that made them more relatable to each other and thus more likely to collaborate . Such research clusters might make it exponentially more difficult than it was lets say 20 years ago for outsiders to have their papers accepted at top avenues . But both your answer and Krause's convinced me that I shouldn't make such argument.

If there are more people per paper and the same number of papers per conference, then there should be more people with papers in top conferences, not fewer.
I would not recommend making this argument. Your work and the venues you publish in are what they are. Some people may recognize the environment you work in is not the same as some others when they look at your contributions, others may not.
In a paper with fewer authors it is more clear what you've contributed; a paper in a top venue with a hundred authors may not indicate that most of them could produce similar work independently if hired at a different institution that is not part of one of these big collaborative projects.

The argument would have been that the author teams tend to be from elite institutions, primarily US universities who are more culturally compatible or have other things in common. Such research clusters might make it exponentially more difficult than it was lets say 20 years ago for outsiders to have their papers accepted at top avenues . But both your answer and Buffy's convinced me that I shouldn't make such argument.

@Kupp That doesn't have anything to do with the length of the author list.

No doubt a lot depends on the specifics of your situation, and the particular grant application that you are writing. However, in many countries there is an increasing awareness that 'contextual factors' should be taken into account when assessing performance, so that people are judged relative to the opportunities that they have had and the challenges that they have faced.
As a result, it may be appropriate to try and highlight areas where you feel you have been disadvantaged compared to others. However, this is something that needs to be done carefully: you want to focus the reader's attention on positive aspects of your CV, rather than highlighting possible weaknesses and then making 'excuses' for them.
Your goal is to ensure that the reader understands the context and norms against which your CV should be judged (with, of course, a particular focus on those aspects where your profile looks good). For example, rather than saying "My region only has low-ranking universities", you might say "I studied at X, which is the highest-ranked university in country Y". "As is usual in country Y, the papers arising from my PhD are co-authored with my adviser only." "I have given keynote presentations at the leading regional conferences in my field; prohibitive costs have prevented me from attending major international meetings (typical annual travel budget: US$Z)."
